# Recursive javascript requests: delay between requests gets bigger with time...?

Tags: javascript, recursion, httprequest, fetch-api

in my Javascript application the user can press a button, in order to continuously fetch data from a server.

Pressing the button triggers a function, which performs a HTTP request to the server. After the request is completed successfully, this function calls itself recursively again and again. The function is escaped if the user presses the button again or a specific limit is reached.

Now my problem is, that by each recursion the delay between each request gets bigger. This can be visualized in the screenshot I took from the developer tools of my browser:

[image]

The blue lines are my sets of requests in each function. The white empty slots between the sets of requests get longer.

This is how my code is structured:

```js
async function startContinousFetch() {
  addContinousData(true);
}

async function addContinousData() {
  addNewData().then((resp) => {
    if (LOGSLIMIT != null && Logs.length > LOGSLIMIT) {
      stopContinousFetch();
      return;
    }
    //Unexpected error, promise didn't resolve with true;
    if (resp == false) {
      //Error handling
    }
    if (continousFetch) {
      addContinousData();
    }
  })
}
function addNewData() {
  return new Promise(async resolve => {
    try {
      //Various http requests are here
      await fetchData();
      //Add, organize and manipulate data in the global "Logs" array
      handleLogs();
      //Resolve promise
      resolve(true)
    } catch (e) {
      resolve(false, e)
    }
  })
}
```

Why do the delays get longer? What is my mistake here?
It is clear to me that my function waits till the response, so there is a delay. But why does this delay get bigger every time.
In the dev tools, the request time does not get any longer, just the time in between.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The application is probably getting more and more slowed down by the data that's being added.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This was also my guess. However I checked the task manager and the application doesn't seem to allocate way more resources (RAM and CPU) than at the beginning...

Comment: Does it need to render all the data?

Comment: Yes, as much as possible.

Comment: Then maybe the rendering itself is the problem.

Comment: Ok so your assumption is that rendering the data takes more and more time, as the data size grows?

Comment: Yea, wouldn't be the first time I've seen that. It's pretty easy to test: Disable only the rendering, and keep fetching data.

Comment: Ok, also the UI gets slower with increasing data size. 
I render the data by drawing rectangles on a HTML canvas... can this be improved at all?

Comment: Does the canvas need to re-draw everything every time data gets fetched? Or does it only have to add new data?

Comment: Yes I need to redraw the whole canvas.

Comment: So as the data grow, the canvas has more and more to draw. Would it be possible to change it so it only draws new data?

Comment: Also I did a bit of testing here, it seems like two functions slow down:
1) I run nested for loops to check, if some of the new data is already present in the big array. So this takes more time, as the global data array gets bigger...
2) Drawing the canvas seems to be the bottleneck, as it gets redrawn by each recursion with the data getting bigger.

I think I'll have to figure out a way to only draw new data.

Comment: I hope you can find a solution!