# Javascript function which draws on canvas takes way too much time...?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, canvas

I already posted a question on this issue: [Recursive javascript requests: delay between requests gets bigger with time...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73582325/recursive-javascript-requests-delay-between-requests-gets-bigger-with-time?noredirect=1#comment129939052_73582325)

My problem is that I run a function which triggers a loop which continuously fetches data from a server and draws it on a canvas.

I did some testing and the canvas drawing part takes the longest, as here I iterate through the entire dataset and draw every element, so that I have an overview of the data fetched.
As this takes a lot of time, the next request is delayed and there are large gaps where no data is fetched.

I can think of two possible solutions:

1. Preferred method: Run the whole canvas drawing process on a different thread or somehow in the background, separate from the main function. It is not an issue for my application if the data is visualized later than it is fetched. But how could I implement this in Javascript?
2. Don't redraw the whole overview and only add the new data. But as my canvas represents an overview for the whole fetched data, I would need to scale down every element in the canvas to the new length and then add the new data. However here I can't find a method to scale down the already drawn elements to a new length... Is this even a realistic approach?

Thanks

EDIT: Code added

```
function drawScrollChart(Logs) {

overviewContext.clearRect(0, 0, overviewCanvas.width, overviewCanvas.height);

overviewContext.globalAlpha = 0.45;
var startY = 0;
var startX = 0;
var grd = 0;
var scale = 5;

var measurementDuration = ((MeasurementPeriods[MeasurementPeriods.length - 1].end - MeasurementPeriods[0].start) / 1000)
var xscale = (overviewCanvas.width / window.devicePixelRatio) / measurementDuration;

overviewContext.beginPath();

for (var i = 1; i < Logs.length; i++) {

    if (Logs[i].event == startEvent) {


        startY = ((overviewCanvas.height / scaleRatio) - 10) - (scale * block_ident);
        startX = ((Logs[i].timestamp / 1000) * xscale);

        grd = overviewContext.createLinearGradient(startX, startY, startX, startY + scale);
        grd.addColorStop(0, getStartCol(block_ident));
        grd.addColorStop(1, getEndCol(block_ident));
        overviewContext.fillStyle = grd;

        overviewContext.fillRect(startX, startY, ((Logs[i].durationWithoutInterrupt / 1000) * xscale), scale);

        if ((i + 1) >= Logs.length) {

            overviewContext.fillRect(startX, startY, ((Logs[i].durationWithInterrupt / 1000) * xscale), scale);

        } else {

            if (Logs[i + 1].event == endEvent) {

                overviewContext.fillRect(startX, startY, ((Logs[i].durationWithoutInterrupt / 1000) * xscale), scale);

            } else {

                overviewContext.fillRect(startX, startY, ((Logs[i].durationWithInterrupt / 1000) * xscale), scale);

            }
        }

    }

    if (Logs[i].event == continueEvent) {


        startY = ((overviewCanvas.height / scaleRatio) - 10) - (scale * block_ident);
        startX = ((Logs[i].timestamp / 1000) * xscale);

        grd = overviewContext.createLinearGradient(startX, startY, startX, startY + scale);
        grd.addColorStop(0, getStartCol(block_ident));
        grd.addColorStop(1, getEndCol(block_ident));
        overviewContext.fillStyle = grd;

        overviewContext.fillRect(startX, startY, ((Logs[i].durationWithInterrupt / 1000) * xscale), scale);

        overviewContext.fill();
    }

}


for (var i = 0; i < MeasurementPeriods.length - 1; i++) {
    overviewContext.globalAlpha = 0.75;

    var startY = ((overviewCanvas.height / scaleRatio) - 10) - (scale * block_ident);
    var startX = (((MeasurementPeriods[i].end - MeasurementPeriods[0].start) / 1000) * xscale);

    var grd = overviewContext.createLinearGradient(startX, startY, startX, startY + scale);
    grd.addColorStop(0, 'rgb(255,0,0)');
    grd.addColorStop(1, 'rgb(255,150,150)');
    overviewContext.fillStyle = grd;

    overviewContext.beginPath();

    var width = (((MeasurementPeriods[i + 1].start - MeasurementPeriods[i].end) / 1000) * xscale);

    overviewContext.fillRect(startX, startY, width, scale);

}

}
```

EDIT2: Dataset sample:

There are around 25 000 of these items, but technically my application should allow way and way more of these items. The block ident varies between -1 and 5-6.

```
{
    "block_ident": -1,
    "event": "e",
    "timestamp": 0,
    "durationWithInterrupt": 0,
    "durationWithoutInterrupt": 0
},
{
    "block_ident": 1,
    "event": "s",
    "timestamp": 0,
    "durationWithInterrupt": 16640,
    "durationWithoutInterrupt": 16640
},
{
    "block_ident": 1,
    "event": "e",
    "timestamp": 16640,
    "durationWithInterrupt": 0,
    "durationWithoutInterrupt": 0
},
{
    "block_ident": -1,
    "event": "s",
    "timestamp": 16640,
    "durationWithInterrupt": 1132288,
    "durationWithoutInterrupt": 1132288
},
{
    "block_ident": -1,
    "event": "e",
    "timestamp": 1148928,
    "durationWithInterrupt": 0,
    "durationWithoutInterrupt": 0
},
{
    "block_ident": 3,
    "event": "s",
    "timestamp": 1148928,
    "durationWithInterrupt": 24064,
    "durationWithoutInterrupt": 24064
},
{
    "block_ident": 3,
    "event": "e",
    "timestamp": 1172992,
    "durationWithInterrupt": 0,
    "durationWithoutInterrupt": 0
},
```

Comment: In neither this question nor the older one did you include any code to illustrate what the drawing function is actually doing.

Comment: Show your canvas drawing methods. We can't optimize code we don't see. Chances are you can make huge improvements, e.g by composing only a few big subpathes instead of drawing a lot of simple ones, by avoiding context property switches, maybe even avoiding bugs like a forgotten `beginPath` etc. You could use an OffscreenCanvas to offload to a worker, but browser support still isn't great, and that won't make things magically faster. Maybe it would be better to do the calculations in a Worker, maybe it would be worth investing in webGL, but once again we can't tell without seeing your code.

Comment: I now edited the question with drawing code

Comment: Wow, one new gradient per item, and several fillRect calls. Could you also include a sample (small) dataset so we can see how the data varies. For one, the last loop could use the same gradient that you'd transform instead of creating a new one per item. Then it might be possible to rewrite all these fillRects with multiple `rect()` calls and a single `fill()`.

Comment: I included a dataset in my question.